# Set minimal length for sfdp laying, GraphViz

Tags: graph, graphviz

Is it possible to change the length between nodes with sftp laying? It is too small for labels.

```
digraph aNet {
    graph [layout=sfdp, overlap=prism, overlap_scaling=-20];
    _0 -> _1 [ label = "set"; ]
    _1 -> _2 [ label = "get"; ]
    _2 -> _3 [ label = "move"; ]
    _0 -> _2 [ label = "put"; ]
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add [`sep`](http://www.graphviz.org/content/attrs#dsep) attribute:

```
digraph aNet {
   graph [layout=sfdp, overlap=prism, overlap_scaling=-20, sep="+25,25"];
    _0 -> _1 [ label = "set";  ]
    _1 -> _2 [ label = "get";  ]
    _2 -> _3 [ label = "move";  ]
    _0 -> _2 [ label = "put";  ]
}
```

Comment: Wow, it works! Thank you :) How could I missed it when I searched through attributes...